# What does $$this mean in MongoDB Aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In [a Mongo Aggregation example I've encountered](http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/how-to-match-a-strict-subset-of-an-array-in-order) the expression `$$this`, but cannot find a reference to it in the MongoDB documentation (not even in the documentation about [aggregation variables](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/))

Here is the sample data:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "actions" : [ 2, 6, 3, 8, 5, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "actions" : [ 6, 4, 2, 8, 4, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "actions" : [ 6, 4, 6, 4, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "actions" : [ 6, 8, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "actions" : [ 6, 8 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "actions" : [ 6, 3, 11, 8, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : 7, "actions" : [ 6, 3, 8 ] }
```

Here is the code

Here is the code I'm looking at:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match:{actions:{$all:[6,3,8]}}},
    {$project:{actions638:{$map:{
       input:{$range:[0,{$subtract:[{$size:"$actions"},2]}]},
       in:{$slice:["$actions","$$this",3]}
    }}}}
])
```

and here is the output

```
{ "_id" : 1, "actions638" : [ [ 2, 6, 3 ], [ 6, 3, 8 ], [ 3, 8, 5 ], [ 8, 5, 3 ] ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "actions638" : [ [ 6, 4, 2 ], [ 4, 2, 8 ], [ 2, 8, 4 ], [ 8, 4, 3 ] ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "actions638" : [ [ 6, 8, 3 ] ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "actions638" : [ [ 6, 3, 11 ], [ 3, 11, 8 ], [ 11, 8, 3 ] ] }
{ "_id" : 7, "actions638" : [ [ 6, 3, 8 ] ] }
```

Comment: Some additional references: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#field-path-and-system-variables and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/

Comment: These don't cover `$$this` though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$$this` refers to the current item inside the array that is being processed by the `$map` function.

An alternative is to use the `as` property so that instead of referring to `$$this` you refer to the name you provided in the `as`. For example ([from the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/))

```
db.grades.aggregate(
   [
      { $project:
         { adjustedGrades:
            {
              $map:
                 {
                   input: "$quizzes",
                   as: "grade",
                   in: { $add: [ "$$grade", 2 ] }
                 }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

Comment: $$this can also be used in $filter function.