# MongoDB - Self join with filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection `users` as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d6"), "email": "u1@mail.com", "user_type" : "1", "grade" : "A1", "room_id" : ObjectId("580557d4094a4514fc1291d6") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d7"), "email": "u2@mail.com", "user_type" : "2", "grade" : "A2", "room_id" : ObjectId("580557d4094a4514fc1291d6") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d8"), "email": "u3@mail.com", "user_type" : "3", "grade" : "A2", "room_id" : ObjectId("580557d4094a4514fc1291d6") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291d9"), "email": "u4@mail.com", "user_type" : "2", "grade" : "A2", "room_id" : ObjectId("580557d4094a4514fc1291d7") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291e6"), "email": "u5@mail.com", "user_type" : "3", "grade" : "A1", "room_id" : ObjectId("580557d4094a4514fc1291d7") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291e7"), "email": "u6@mail.com", "user_type" : "3", "grade" : "A2", "room_id" : ObjectId("580557d4094a4514fc1291d7") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291e8"), "email": "u7@mail.com", "user_type" : "2", "grade" : "A1", "room_id" : ObjectId("580557d4094a4514fc1291d8") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570557d4094a4514fc1291e9"), "email": "u8@mail.com", "user_type" : "3", "grade" : "A1", "room_id" : ObjectId("580557d4094a4514fc1291d8") }
```

I want to find email ids of users of type 2 having `grade` A2, along with their roommates having the same `room_id` but `user_type` 3 (`grade` does not matter for roommates). So the result data should look like this:

```
{"email": "u2@mail.com", "roommates": [{"email": "u3@mail.com"}]}
{"email": "u4@mail.com", "roommates": [{"email": "u5@mail.com"}, {"email": "u6@mail.com"}]}
```

How do I do this in MongoDB? I have a background in SQL so I am thinking of a self join, but I guess there are other ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the (concept/direction) of self-join `users` collection is correct.

1. `$lookup` - Join `users` collection by `room_id` and return `roommates` array.
2. `$match` - Filter the document by `user_type`, `grade` and `roommates.user_type`.
3. `$project` - Decorate the output document.

   3.1. `$map` - Iterate the `roommates` array and returns an array.

   3.1.1. `$filter` - Filter the document with `user_type` in `roommates` array.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "room_id",
      foreignField: "room_id",
      as: "roommates"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      user_type: "2",
      grade: "A2",
      "roommates.user_type": "3"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      email: 1,
      roommates: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$roommates",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.user_type",
                  "3"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          in: {
            email: "$$this.email"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TxZ3QBACUI8)

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain what does `$$this` mean here?

Comment: `$$this` is an variable for referring to current (iterate) document, which normally use in `$filter`, `$map` or `$reduce.` You may refer to: [What does $$this mean in MongoDB Aggregation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863541/what-does-this-mean-in-mongodb-aggregation) .

Comment: Another alternative of `$$this`  is declaring the variable name using `as: example` in `$filter`, `$map` or `$reduce`. Then you use `$$example` as refer to the current document.