# Retrieving sorted values in an array not equal to an ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my database schema for films:

[image]

I have this code which retrieves the `title` and `reviews` array of objects sorted in descending order of creation date (working):

```
db.films.findOne({ _id: ObjectId('64d69473da87c0c91ae7c596') }, 
     {title:1, reviews:{$sortArray:{input:"$reviews", sortBy:{creationdate:-1}}} } )
```

I'm trying to extend this to find all the reviews with the element is not equal to a specific `userid`:

```
db.films.findOne(
      { _id: ObjectId("64d69473da87c0c91ae7c596") },
      {
        title: 1,
        updatedreviews: {
          $sortArray: {
            input: [
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $not: {
                      $in: [
                        ObjectId("64d95f9b4ce0a13e8fc37567"),
                        "$reviews.userid",
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                  "$reviews",
                  null,
                ],
              },
            ],
            sortBy: { "$reviews.creationdate": -1 },
          },
        },
      }
    );
```

It isn't working: It's retrieving `null`. I tried the opposite which is equal to `$in` the specific `userid` but it's returning all the reviews:

```
db.films.findOne(
      { _id: ObjectId("64d69473da87c0c91ae7c596") },
      {
        title: 1,
        updatedreviews: {
          $sortArray: {
            input: [
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                      $in: [
                        ObjectId("64d95f9b4ce0a13e8fc37567"),
                        "$reviews.userid",
                      ],
                  },
                  "$reviews",
                  null,
                ],
              },
            ],
            sortBy: { "$reviews.creationdate": -1 },
          },
        },
      }
);
```

Any idea on how to fix this problem and retrieve all the reviews not made by that particular user's `ObjectId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`$filter`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator to filter the matching element(s) in the `reviews` array.

```
db.films.findOne({
  _id: ObjectId("64d69473da87c0c91ae7c596")
},
{
  title: 1,
  updatedreviews: {
    $sortArray: {
      input: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$reviews",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              ObjectId("64d95f9b4ce0a13e8fc37567"),
              "$$this.userid"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      sortBy: {
        "creationdate": -1
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1FqC18UY56L)

Comment: This is working. I understand everything in your code except: `"$$this.userid"`. What does the `$$` and `this` do and why `"$reviews.userid"` won't work here?

Comment: Hi, [`$$this`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50863541/8017690) is referred to the current iterated element in the array. The reason why `$reviews.userid` is not working as you are using the `$not` `$in` operator to find whether the specific `userid` is not in the array. If it doesn't exist, the whole `reviews` array will be returned. Otherwise, when it existed, `null` value will be returned. Which both results are not what you wanted as what you want is to retrieve the element with the `userId` not equal to specific id.